# What happens when I call a function that calls a function with more parameters than I have entered

Tags: parameters, prolog

I'm currently learning Prolog and I encountered something I don't quite understand and I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

So the thing is when I have a procedure like this:

```
a(X):- b(X, Y).
b(X, Y):- c(X), ==(Y, 10).
```

What Is `Y` going to be then? Is it going to be a random number or will `==(Y, 10)` be ignored in the procedure? Is a procedure that calls a function with an unknown parameter doomed to be false?

I would really appreciate an answer to this.

Comment: `I'm currently learning Prolog` If you are teaching yourself by looking at code, then please don't do it that way and instead get a book. Do you know about [syntactic unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Syntactic_unification_of_first-order_terms)?

Comment: Prolog has *predicates*, not *functions*. There is a difference. `a(X):- b(X, Y).` in this case, `Y` is a singleton and you'd get a warning to that effect. If `b` instantiates `Y`, the result will be ignored, or if not, it will remain unbound or uninstantiated. `Y` serves no purpose in this predicate clause. That doesn't mean the predicate will fail. A call to `a(X)` will succeed as long as the call to `b(X, Y)` succeeds. Also, `Y` will just be ignored. This can be intentional, and so you can write `a(X) :- b(X, _).` to avoid warnings. `==(Y, 10)` may be written as `Y == 10`.